# Converting circular structure to JSON in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have 5 records and when i try to get those i am facing the following error,can someone help me please.Thanks

My nodejs,

```
exports.searchlistbyfirstname = function (req, res) {
  var params = req.params;
  var record= db.collection('profile');
  record.find( { $text: { $search: params.id} }, (err, result) => {
   if (err){ return console.log(err)
    }
      if(result){
            response = {status:'success',data:result};
        } else{
            response = {status:'fail'};
        }
      res.send(response);
  });

};
```

Comment: Where is the `params` variable used? Try to fetch the data using the cursor's `toArray()` method as `record.find().toArray((err, result) => { ... });`

Comment: Cridam,i am not using any params here and i just want to get the total records in my db

Comment: Thank you,i got it......

Comment: Still, you need to use the cursor's `toArray()` method because the result you are getting is a cursor object; you would want to fetch the data from the cursor using the `toArray()` method as `record.find({ "$text": { "$search": params.id} }).toArray((err, result) => { ... })`

Comment: OHH k but here i am trying to search in firstname and params.id has search parameter but where i  should compare it with my firstname

Comment: `record.find({ "firstname": { "$regex": new RegExp(params.id) } }).toArray((err, result) => { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

$text and $search is useful when you want to search multiple fields in a collection like you want to search a string that can be in multiple fields like firstname, lastname etc so in that case you can create indexing on those keys as following ways:
**Schema level:**

```
new Schema({
    firstname:{type: String, index: true},
    firstname:{type: String, index: true}
    .....
 });
```

Using ensureIndex:

```
profile.collection.ensureIndex({firstname:"text",lastname:"text" ....},default_language:"none"},function(err,result){   });
```

**Using $text and $search you can search in other language as well like:**

you have two records:

```
{ "_id" : 7, "subject" : "coffee and cream", "author" : "efg", "views" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 1, "subject" : "coffee", "author" : "xyz", "views" : 50 }
```

and you want to search in Spanish then you can do that in following way:

```
db.articles.find(
   { $text: { $search: "leche", $language: "es" } }
)
```

The query returns the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 5, "subject" : "Café Con Leche", "author" : "abc", "views" : 200 }
{ "_id" : 8, "subject" : "Cafe con Leche", "author" : "xyz", "views" : 10 }
```

For more details refer to this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/