# How to find count of results in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to find count of the result but I'm not sure how to use it. Can anyone suggest help please

```
  exports.shownotifications = function (req, res) {
  var params = req.params;console.log(params)
    var record= db.collection('requests');
    var item = {"sent_id": params.id,"status":1};console.log(item)
  record.find(item).toArray((err, result) => {
   if (err){ return console.log(err)
    }
      if(result){
            response = {status:'success',data:result};console.log(response)
        } else{
            response = {status:'fail',data:[]};
        }
      res.send(response);
  });

};
```

Comment: Am maybe result.length? as result will be an array.

Comment: What's the use of `toArray()`? why you used here?

Comment: Any chance you're having the same issue with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571093/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [db.collection.count()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.count/#examples)

```
  exports.shownotifications = function(req, res) {
    var params = req.params;
    var record = db.collection('requests');
    var item = {
        "sent_id": params.id,
        "status": 1
    };
    record.count(item), (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
        }
        if (result) {
            response = {
                status: 'success',
                data: result
            };
        } else {
            response = {
                status: 'fail',
                data: []
            };
        }
        res.send(response);
    }
  };
```